# what media query code should be use for user interface

Tags: css, media-queries

My application does not show well on wide and big display firefox os devices? what is a right media query code for all type devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     /*==================================================
```

=            Bootstrap 3 Media Queries             =
==================================================*/

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}



/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Comment: Do you think i must care about resolution or not? when the width of device is bigger so the resolution is bigger also or not?

Comment: Yes, you have to write the resolutions in the media query respective to the device width.

Comment: How can i develop a responsive proportion for HTML tags considering both width and resolution?

Comment: You could use percentage values instead of pixels.For example, with a 6 column grid, each column is 100% ÷ 6 = 16.666667% wide.

Comment: i am gonna use bootstartp. i think it's work for me. thank you again for answer. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are usually application specific, but if you are looking for a generic scheme, you could use what Bootstrap has been using.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Please note, this is assuming you are not using the mobile-first approach. If you are, you would need to use

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```